# How to protect these rhinos?

Tags: biology, post-apocalypse, armors

In my post-apocalyptic world, rhinos are used as beasts of burden. However, in order to survive harsh conditions and harsher predators, they need to have some sort of armor (natural or unnatural). However, I'm not quite sure how that would work. Should they have shells? **How should these rhinos be protected?**

Comment: As opposed to a modern day rhino's incredibly thick hide and large horn?

Comment: Rhinos already *have* armor. (Fun detail: in German, the [Indian rhinoceros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rhinoceros) (*Rhinoceros unicornis*) is called the *Panzernashorn*, the armored-nose-horn beast.)

Comment: What is the threat model they are facing? Without that info is impossible to answer. To be clear: are they facing super wolves? Laser firing tigers? Sneezing skunks?

Answer (score 4):

Hanna-Barbera had the exact same problem for their series the Herculoids.

They addressed that need with Tundro, the up-armored rhino that shoots plasma balls from his forehead horn, because the best defense is a good offense.  A brute of a cargo carrier, mega-traction with its mutant-like ten legs, and the heart of a warrior, always ready to protect his adoptive family -- The Herculoids.
[image: Tundro from the Herculoids]

Comment: OMG I LOVED THAT SHOW!!!

Comment: IKR!  Tundro is the bomb.

Answer (score 3):

Rhinos are already armored powerhouses. Most small arms would do little more than anger them. In a post apocalyptic world, the weapons needed to bring them down without risking a good deal of loss of life would be rare. I'd recommend vanilla rhinos or just slightly toughened hides (rendering them all but immune to small arms fire).

Answer (score 0):

Make story about rhinos a bit longer. They could survive far away from human's settlements. Then, species started to grow up their population at railway speed, because of the human absence. With growing population their habitat also was spreading out, while some day it reached humanity. The only question is how they survived from predator, but this is wild nature, they would survive and reproduce while they have good environment for. Human settlements around with poachers and hunters can break the balance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, as it says nothing about natural or artificial armour.